# Running ARM code in Eclipse on Windows without a development board?

Tags: c, eclipse, arm, gdb

I have a C code that I want to profile for ARM Cortex A53. I am using Eclipse CDT with GNU MCU tools on Windows.

After some trouble with project settings, compiler and linker flags, I have successfully built a project with GNU MCU ARM toolchain.

But...
When I try to run it I get error:

```
Error starting process.
Cannot run program "myproject.elf": Launching failed
```

And when I try to Debug it:

```
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Don't know how to run.
```

Is is at all possible to run (simulate) ARM code without having a development board connected?

Comment: Take a look at `qemu`. There are numerous tutorials on how to use it to emulate different arm boards.

Comment: If you want to profile it you will need the target hardware you are interested in using.

Comment: Alternatively you need any emulator capable of emulating your target system. Of course your development host can not run the target's code if it is not compatible with the target system.

Comment: Thanks. 
Some time ago I did profile a processor without a target hardware; this was Tensilica DSP processor. It was possible because Tensilica provides a so called "instruction set simulator". It is a standard component of the their tools package. It's just a command line tool that takes efl format executable at input, and at output dumps profiling data (`gmon.out`) file. As a last step, I would feed `gmon.out` to `gprof` tool.
I was hoping something like this exists for ARM. Maybe [ARMulator](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0058/d/armulator-basics/about-armulator)?